# String too Long Exception C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am using the following code. I am passing a string f to startinfo.Arguments property. I am sending a JSON string and getting **(STRING TOO LONG EXCEPTION)**

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
startInfo.Arguments = f;
```

Comment: Why would you want to pass a JSON string as the command line arguments to WinWord.exe? What do you expect that to accomplish? Fundamentally, if you find you've got too much information to pass on the command line, you should provide the data in another way - e.g. put it in a file.

Comment: and how long is `f` exactly? Also: why are you invoking `winword.exe` from asp.net : that is explicitly not supported.

Comment: Good for you! But what do you want to know?

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you give an example for that. I tried with a text document but didn't get success in it.

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to achieve, so how can I give you an example?

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly mentioned in the help section which opens when you hover on `Arguments` or press `F12` that,

> File type–specific arguments that the system can associate with the
>   application specified in the
>   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.FileName property. The default is
>   an empty string (""). The length of the arguments added to the length
>   of the full path to the process must be less than 2080.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

See [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). You're "doing it wrong" if you're trying to use the winword exe from an ASP.NET application. I suggest you find a library that is meant for working with Word documents server side, as you'll just encounter a lot of headaches if you continue down the path you're on.